# How do I give all the permissions to a file for a single user that's not me?

Tags: shell, shell-script, permissions, users

When I want to grant access to another user to my file, I use `chmod 777 file`, but if I want to be sure I'm granting permission just for that user, how can I do it?

**-- update**

The file is owned by "root", so it's mine if I access it with `sudo`, I suppose (or maybe I'm confused.. please correct me).

I want to share a folder called `/Data` in the root. The other user I want to share it is the root of an embedded system, which I'm accessing with telnet and NFS.

The files inside `/Data` are generated by me, and every time I generate them, I have to use the command `chmod 777 /Data` so I can access them from the embedded system.

I'm using Ubuntu in my computer, and a compiled-here-linux in the embedded system.

Comment: @Tom: Please give more details. Is this a file owned by you? Where on the computer system is it located? Is the other user on the same system? Also, some more details about the use case would be helpful. If you just want to share a file with another person without anyone else being able to access it, there are variety of options, including pgp/gpg encryption. The traditional Unix permission model is a bit restricive, but you might want to consider acl if you are using Linux. What OS are you using?

Comment: Since you are root (mentioned in a comment below), can't you just use the user's name? For example `chown bob file`. Or if you want both the owner and the group `chown bob.users file`.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha please, see my update

Comment: @Tom: Doing anything as root, unless absolutely necessary, is a really, really, bad idea. This is usually one of the first things one learns about unix, sometimes the hard way. Unless you really need to be root to access the files, don't do it as root (or sudo, which is equivalent). If you want to restrict permissions, there are better, safer ways to do it.

Comment: @Tom: I'm not sure if I understood the entire issue correctly, but if you want to share files between users, and want to be able to override the umask, acl is a reasonable way to go. This does assume the users you are sharing among are on the same system. acl is a linux extension of the basic unix permissions system.

Comment: @faif @Faheem Mitha I know that the way I'm doing is not the better way. So, what's the better way? How do I give all the permissions to a file for a single user that's not me (in the better way possible)?

Comment: @Tom: Sit down and read a tutorial on acl, and see if it works for you. but clarify first, is this for users on the same system?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: not. It's one user in a Ubuntu system (in a pc), and another in a embedded system.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: I'll read about ACL, thanks

Comment: @Tom: acl might not work for you then.

Comment: @Tom: So, basically what you are doing is creating a file on your local system as root, then attempting to access that file via NFS from your embedded system, also as root (I just want to make sure I am correctly understanding your problem)?   What happens when you do this, w/out doing anything else?  Do you get an error message?  Can you please post that in your question?  There is no reason what you are trying to do should not work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to find a group that only you and that user is part of, and give correct permission to the group, not the world.

Could be easier with access control lists, if available.

Comment: Can't I give the user name for the chmod?

Comment: @Tom `chmod` changes the file mode bits; they don't have that kind of flexibility. You set read/write/execute for the owner, people in the owner's group, and everyone; that's it. If you need something more you should look into access control lists

Comment: You can use this to figure out which groups you both belong to: `wdiff -t <(groups $USER) <(groups other_user)`

Comment: So, if we both don't belong to a common group, how can I make us part of a same group? (I have access to both users here)

Comment: @Tom: `groupadd GROUPNAME` to create the group, then `usermod -a -G GROUPNAME USERNAME` to add a user to the group. I also recommend reading the man pages of both commands.

Answer (score 3):

If you own the file, `setfacl -m u:otheruser:rwx filename`

If not, or if your filesystem doesn't support extended acls, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: I'm out of luck, there's no `setfacl` command.

Comment: @Tom: `apt-get install acl` or similar.

Comment: the user name in the other machine (an embedded system) is "root", so I tried with `sudo setfacl -m u:root:rwx /Data` but I got `setfacl: /Data: Operation not supported`

Comment: The file is mine, in my root user, of my computer. So it should work with `sudo`..

Comment: @Tom: You need to mount your partition(s) with support for acl. See the docs.

Comment: @tom @faheem This may involve updating the filesystem to allow acls - if you're on an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem, `tune2fs -o acl <filesystem>` where `<filesystem>` is the filesystem mounted to /Data as described by the `mount` and `df` command.

Comment: Why should ACL's be needed in this case?

Comment: @gabe: standard UNIX file permissions only have bits for the file owning user, file owning group and 'others'. If you want something more specific, you need ACLs.

Comment: @tom There's also the problem that the 'root' user is explicitly treated differently via NFS -- IIRC NFS maps root over to nobody before it checks access rights.

Comment: @Shadur:  That's a problem that is easy to override w/in your NFS exports file.

Comment: @gabe Easy, yes. Wise, not necessarily...